# RxJava2 TestSubscriber assertEmpty always true

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-testing, android-room

I am trying to test some RxJava code using `TestSubsriber`. The data is coming from `Room` ORM as `Flowable<Task>`.

**This is how my DAO class looks right now.**

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDao {

    @Insert()
    long insertTask(TaskEntity task);

    @Delete
    int deleteTask(TaskEntity task);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE status = :taskStatus ORDER BY created_at DESC")
    Flowable<List<TaskEntity>> getAllTasks(String taskStatus);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE id = :taskId")
    Flowable<TaskEntity> getTask(String taskId);

    @Update()
    int updateTask(TaskEntity updatedTask);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_table")
    int rowCount();
}
```

I am trying to test `getTask()` method. Here the exact test method that is failing.

```
@Test
public void getTask_getSavedTask_returnsTask() {

    Long resp = mTaskDao.insertTask(taskEntity);
    assertThat(resp, is(1L));

    assertThat(mTaskDao.rowCount(), is(1));

    Flowable<TaskEntity> response = mTaskDao.getTask(taskEntity.getTaskId());
    TestSubscriber<TaskEntity> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

    response.subscribe(testSubscriber);
    testSubscriber.assertNoErrors();
    testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1);
}
```

This code snippet fails at `testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1)` method.

The model is getting saved in db since the returned value from insert call is > 1. Also the row count is getting increased.

I tried running the same kind of code from outside the test environment (from an activity) and it's working fine there.

Comment: Is `taskEntity.getTaskId()` a given value or is it auto generated by the `insertTask`? If so, you are most likely calling `getTask` with the wrong id.

Comment: @akarnokd, it's a given value. I have defined a static variable with a fixed taskId. 
https://gist.github.com/sahilpatel14/3af81f438c44f87a45fa573158fd25cf

Comment: Does it work if you don't use Flowable as a return type for `getTask()`. Is there some transaction involved or commit missing?

Comment: I tried with Optional and it was working. However, I have a few queries where Flowable is necessary `Flowable<List<TaskEntity>> getAllTasks(String taskStatus);`. I am getting the same problem in testing those cases too. This is a branch for my repo's current state. https://github.com/sahilpatel14/AwesomeTodoListApp/tree/test-bug

Comment: Please make sure you are running with the latest RxJava 2.1.14 (as of now) as dependent libraries usually don't get updated to the latest: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid#binaries

Comment: I have explicitly added the latest RxJava dependency 2.1.14. Still facing the issue. `java.lang.AssertionError: Value counts differ; Expected: 1, Actual: 0 (latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0)
`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your DAO runs asynchronously and the `TestSubscriber` doesn't receive an answer immediately. Change the test to this and it should work:

```java
testSubscriber.awaitCount(1, BaseTestConsumer.TestWaitStrategy.SLEEP_1MS, 5000);

testSubscriber.assertNoTimeout();
testSubscriber.assertNoErrors();
testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1);
```

Comment: It's working now. I understand what was wrong with it and how you solved it. However, I am still confused about this behaviour. In general, most of the data sources run asynchronously. How does pro devs deal with testing those code fragments? Do they add this `awaitCount()` method to every test? Or maybe there is a more straightforward way of doing it. It's not really relevant since you have already fixed my problem. I am just curious. :)

Comment: If the source is known to be async and finite, we use `awaitDone`. If the source may not end but we know how many items to expect, we use `awaitCount`.

Comment: I tried this solution. It works fine for a single test but when I run a few tests together, the results vary. Sometimes test-4 passes and when I add test-5, it fails. https://github.com/sahilpatel14/AwesomeTodoListApp/tree/test-bug

Comment: Why would you `awaitCount` in the createDb?

Comment: I just moved the TestSubscriber initialisation code to @Before annotated method. I thought awaitCount is also a part of initialisation. Required to be done only once. Is is incorrect?

Comment: That logic of yours makes no sense. You assert the current state with `TestObserver`s as it evolves.

Comment: I have changed the logic and moved `TestSubscriber` initialisation and `awaitCount()` to every test method. The issue is still exists. I think it has to do with the timeout value that is passed. I tried to vary it *(1s for first test, 5s for second)* and it works. Still confused about the whole behaviour.

Comment: found [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) article on testing ROOM orm with RxJava. I made the suggested changes from the article but I am back to original problem. https://github.com/sahilpatel14/AwesomeTodoListApp/tree/v1